# What does the x-coredata path mean when I 'po' the core data object in lldb?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I print an object description for a core data object in lldb I'll sometimes get the following object description:

(lldb) po my_challenge_object
 (entity: Challenge; id: 0x170433460 <**x-coredata:///Challenge/t52BD558C-A8FE-4064-A8BE-217A837521E52**> ; data: {...})

If I print the same object at a later time, I'll sometimes see the 'x-coredata' path change.

(entity: Challenge; id: 0x170433460 <**x-coredata://50232AB5-7372-4628-9F00-51BDB1A5C96D/Challenge/t52BD558C-A8FE-4064-A8BE-217A837521E52**> ; data: {...})

My question is, what does that path mean and why is it changing? What does the addition of '50232AB5-7372-4628-9F00-51BDB1A5C96D' tell me about my object, in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you first print the object it has not been assigned to a persistent store:

```
(lldb) po my_challenge_object
<Challenge: 0x1700da1d0> (entity: Challenge; id: 0x170433460 <x-coredata:///Challenge/t52BD558C-A8FE-4064-A8BE-217A837521E52> ; data: {...})
```

Thats why there are three slashes after the colon in the managed object ID.

In the second instance, it has been assigned to a persistent store with the identifier "50232AB5-7372-4628-9F00-51BDB1A5C96D".

```
<Challenge: 0x1700da1d0> (entity: Challenge; id: 0x170433460 <**x-coredata://50232AB5-7372-4628-9F00-51BDB1A5C96D/Challenge/t52BD558C-A8FE-4064-A8BE-217A837521E52**> ; data: {...})
```

The structure of a managed object ID URI is generally as follows:

> x-coredata://[Store UUID]/[Entity Name]/[Primary Key]

**Note:** that the [Primary Key] section is store specific, and may refer to the pk of a sqlite row or some other identifier in an XML or Binary store.

The store UUID is available from the store's metadata dictionary, or by asking an instance of NSPersistentStore for its identifier:

```
NSLog(@"Store Identifier: %@", [store identifier]);
```

Comment: Do you know any techniques for drilling down into this data?

Answer (score 2):

Each `NSManagedObject` has a `objectID`.
What you see in the object description is

```
[[object objectID] URIRepresentation]
```

From the documentation of `objectID`:

> **Important:**  If the receiver has not yet been saved, the object ID is a
>   temporary value that will change when the object is saved.

And from the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> An `NSManagedObjectID` object is a universal identifier for a managed
>   object, and provides basis for uniquing in the Core Data Framework. A
>   managed object ID uniquely identifies the same managed object both
>   between managed object contexts in a single application, and in
>   multiple applications (as in distributed systems). Like the primary
>   key in the database, an identifier contains the information needed to
>   exactly describe an object in a persistent store, although the
>   detailed information is not exposed. The framework completely
>   encapsulates the “external” information and presents a clean object
>   oriented interface.

One situation where you actually need the managed object ID is when passing a
managed object from one managed object context to different context.

Comment: So, it sounds like if I have not saved the object yet, the URIRepresentation for the shouldn't change. If that's the case, I'm confused about why the URIRepresentation is changing.

Comment: @kross: That's a good question. Looking at your question again, both object IDs look like a *temporary* ID (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354485/using-a-concise-form-of-nsmanagedobjectid-uri for an analysis of permanent IDs), but I haven't actually seen an ID like the second one. What "happens" to the object in-between? Do you use nested contexts? - On the other hand, the exact representation should not matter and is not documented.